# Using VBA with Checkboxes and vLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, save, vlookup

I'm trying to make a small info sheet that has a drop down menu with a bunch of names. When you pick a name it automatically fills out a bunch of info on them. I also want it to have a checkbox that is checked if that person has a job. The problem I'm having calling/saving that value.

I'm trying to make it so all the saved information is on a second hidden sheet. Calling the information is easy enough. But changing it and having it save over what was previously there seems really hard.

Comment: Is the hidden sheet a table of data (people) that is used to populate cells on the front sheet? And when the user clicks a button you want to write the data back into the original table?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the hidden sheet you should reserve one column with all the names and another column with two values that tells wether the person has a job or not, so say either 1/0 or Y/N.

The checkbox click/change event is what causes the column with the Y/N values to change. So I would just simply change the relevant value in the column that has al the Y/N values.

Comment: I have all of that already set up. But how does the checkbox know which of the numbers to change. I can only set it so it changes 1 box.

Comment: For that I would use the index number of the list with all the names. 
Or you could run a for loop in the column with all the names till it matches your search, this is tricky though because you can have more than one person with the same name.